# Можно ли выбрать Потомка через конструктор абстрактного Родителя?

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

Имеется абстрактный класс `Human`, от него наследуются два класса: `Man` и `Woman`. Я создаю экземпляр, но не знаю, мужчина это или женщина.

Как грамотнее всего на практике решается подобная задача?

На данный момент написано следующим образом, но так ведь не делается...

```
class Human {};
class Man : public Human {};
class Woman : public Human {};

Human *createHuman(bool gender); // Возвращает указатель на созданный Man или Woman

int main()
{
    Human *firstHuman = createHuman(1);
}
```

Решается ли эта задача через конструктор класса `Human`?

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема? Что именно вас не устраивает в коде?

(Я бы пол кодировал не числом, а enum'ом.)

Comment: @VladD Я предположил, что можно как-то реализовать это не через отдельную функцию, а через конструктор класса Human.

Human *firstHuman = new Human(1);

А указатель придет на класс Man или Woman

Comment: Через конструктор класса Human нельзя никак: из него может вернуться только Human. Делайте через factory method `createHuman`.

Comment: @artyomdevyatov: Конструктор вызывается после того, как "сырая" память под объект уже выделена. Поэтому очевидно, что в конструкторе уже поздно решать, будет ли это `Man` или `Woman`, ибо в общем случае размеры этих типов могут быть разными. Решение о том, что вы будете создавать, должно быть принято еще до выделения памяти.

Answer (score 5):

Перенесу из комментария:

Через конструктор класса `Human` сделать реализовать нужное не получится: из конструктора `Human` может вернуться лишь тип `Human`. То, что вы используете — factory method, общепринятый способ решения вашей проблемы. Так что вы делаете всё правильно.

---

Я бы лишь заменил `bool gender` на `enum`, поскольку `true` не имеет очевидной привязки ни к одному из полов.